# org.springframework.core.convert.TypeDescriptor Class not found?

Tags: spring, javabeans

I was trying to do experiments about spring IOC and I write ServiceBean as well as a beans.xml file. I try to instantiate a service bean like this in my Application:

```java
public class SpringTrialApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SpringTrialApplication main = new SpringTrialApplication();

        XmlBeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(new ClassPathResource("beans.xml",main.getClass().getClassLoader() ));
        // use service bean:
        ServiceBean service = (ServiceBean)factory.getBean("service");
        // com.ServiceBean service = new com.MyServiceBean();
        service.addUser("bill", "hello");
        service.addUser("tom", "goodbye");
        service.addUser("tracy", "morning");
        System.out.println("tom's password is: " + service.getPassword("tom"));
        if(service.findUser("tom")) {
            service.deleteUser("tom");
        }
    }
}
```

And I can read the beans.xml successfully, but it failed to create a bean due to the not-found class org.springframework.core.convert.TypeDescriptor. Below is my log:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'service' defined in class path resource [beans.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/convert/TypeDescriptor
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:901)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at com.SpringTrialApplication.main(SpringTrialApplication.java:27)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/convert/TypeDescriptor
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:950)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.convert.TypeDescriptor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 9 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

and my beans.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN"
        "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>
    <bean id="service" class="com.MyServiceBean" />
</beans>
```

My workspace like this:
[directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59yru.png)
following dependencies are used in my project:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
```

So is that because spring framework change inner structure in 3.x? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I suggest to use the same version of spring to avoid dependency problems

Comment: Oh!!! Thank you very much! I change them to the same version 3.0.2.RELEASE and it works!!!

Comment: You are welcome, if you can just validate my answer like a useful and make the Stack as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Make the same version in `spring-beans` and `spring-core` resolve the problem.